# Upvote and downvote buttons are activated only after refresh on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, bug, up-votes, google-chrome

If I open a question page in Stack Overflow and leave it for a few seconds, after that upvote and downvote buttons are not working (in Chrome! In Internet Explorer 10 and Firefox it's OK).

Every time I have to refresh the page and vote quickly...

I'm using Chrome 27.0.1453.110. Is it a bug of Stack Overflow or Chrome's?

Comment: I would blame user script you installed at some point. Got such?

Comment: installed user script? do you mean chrome extensions?

Comment: Not really, I mean anything posted on [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/). Never did anything like that?

Comment: Also, work with Chrome JavaScript console open and see if you get errors when trying to click the voting buttons it will help debug the problem.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, yes I've got an error!  
`Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function`

Comment: So it means required JS file wasn't loaded... switch to the "network" tab in the Chrome dev tools and see what exactly fails.